# reference length of regular expression group

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to replace the digits at the end of a filename with hashes, for example **image.0010001.tiff** would become **image.#######.tiff**

Is it possible to do this using a single re.sub method?

This is what I have so far:

```
re.sub('(\d+)(?=\.\w+$)', '#'*len('\g<1>'), 'image.0010001.tiff')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a function to `re.sub` like so:

```
re.sub('(\d+)(?=\.\w+$)', lambda match:'#'*len(match.group(1)), 'image.0010001.tiff')
```